# How do I create a product search engine for my website that will find images and product info?

Tags: php

i am new to PHP and would like to learn how to create a search engine that will show products with there images and information?

i am very willing to learn but just need to be put on the right path and it looks like this is the best place to get the help!

the search facility here is what i'm looking to do http://www.decoratum.com/

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Do you have a pre existing database of products?

Comment: [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) is a really popular choice. You just want an `ecommerce` solution. You could also use eBay.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a product database, your database server may already provide some sort of full-text search option, such as that of MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

If you want something to supplement your database, Solr and Sphinx are fairly popular options: http://php.net/manual/en/refs.search.php